# the connection is not open

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

I have a problem. I wrote this method for opening sql connection. But it did not work.
why didn't this work.

```
public SqlConnection connection( ) 
{
    string DBName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBName"].ToString();
    string ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"].ToString();
    string UserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"].ToString();
    string DBPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBPassword"].ToString();

    EMVTool.OSSPwdProcessor PwdPass = new EMVTool.OSSPwdProcessor();

    String sClearPwd = "";

    if (DBPassword.Length > 40)
        sClearPwd = PwdPass.DecryptPwd(DBPassword);
    else
        sClearPwd = DBPassword;

    string ConnectionString = "Server=" + ServerName + ";Database =" + DBName + ";UID =" + UserId + ";PWD =" + sClearPwd + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    return connect;
}
```

and i am calling the method like that for opening sql connection.

```
connection().Open();
```

Comment: *How* didn't it work? Also, show the relevant code where you actually use the connection instead of where you create it.

Comment: You might also post the resulting `ConnectionString`.

Comment: ... remembering to scrub out username and password.

Comment: @Bartosz without the password...

Comment: Try `(connection() as SqlConnection).Open();`.

Comment: The exception is : "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed". i used an ExecuteReader somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It didn't work because you opened something but then used different instance afterwards.

To make it work, assign the function return value to local  variable:

```
using (SqlConnection  conn = connection())
{
    conn.Open();
    //rest of code...
}
```